# trigger click automatically using jquery to export all graphs as image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, amcharts

I have multiple graphs in a single html page.I am trying to export all the graphs after the complete loading of all the graphs on that page.
I have the script to trigger the click event, but it's not working as I want it.
I want to trigger click button so that it pushes the graph image in an array as base64 encoded then send the data to a php file and save it as an image.

Two images are being created but only one image is proper and the other image is corrupt.

here is my code to graph generation:
https://jsfiddle.net/a1so23dh/2/

here is my php file code:

```
<?php
$data = urldecode($_POST['imageData']);
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
$filename = "images/image".rand(1000,10000).".jpg";
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
?>
```

Any other approach may also work.

Comment: I tried calling it..not working..so i temporarily deleted the code.Can you please try the code on your machine and guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to just use the API methods in AmCharts' events and the AmCharts export plugin API instead of using fake clicks, similar to the first example in [this tutorial](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/export-charts-advanced/). It uses the `rendered` event, but `animationFinished` works as well:

```
"listeners": [{
  "event": "animationFinished",
  "method": function(e) {
    //wait for fabric
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      if (window.fabric) {
        clearTimeout(interval);
        e.chart.export.capture({}, function() {
          this.toJPG({}, function(data) {
             //post base64 string in data to your endpoint directly
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
]
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1so23dh/4/) - note that for debugging purposes I added the exported image to the bottom of the screen to validate that this works.

Comment: Thank you very much.you just saved me.

Answer (score 0):

Your sendAllData() is not called. so I propose some changes, well it's not a full solution but help you.

```
$('*').click(function(e){
    sendAllData();
});



function sendAllData(){
    console.log(dataArray);
    var arsize = dataArray.length;
    console.log("here");
    //execute this function and use the dataArray here  
    //send data to php file
    if(arsize != 0){
       for(i=0;i<=dataArray.length;i++){
          jQuery.post( "a.php", {imageData: encodeURIComponent( dataArray[i] )})
               .done(function( data ) {
                   if(data != 1){
                       console.log( "Data Loaded: " + data );
                   }else{
                       console.log("error");
                   }
          });
        }
    }
}
```

In PHP use below code.

```
<?php
    $data = urldecode($_POST['imageData']);
    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
    list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    //$filename = "images/image".rand(1000,10000).".jpg";
    //file_put_contents($filename, $data);

    $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);

    if ($im !== false) {
         header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
         imagejpeg($im, "uploads/png3.jpeg");
         imagedestroy($im);
    }else{
         echo '1';
    }
 ?>
```

I am able to save the image of first graph i.e bar chart but in the pie chart, I am getting the error.please try this.